# Does node_handle insertion invalidate the handle?

Tags: c++, c++17

Do I understand correctly, that since `std::map`'s node-handle insertion takes r-value:

`insert_return_type std::map::insert(node_type&& nh)`,

the node-handle cannot be used (to change value) after insertion?

```
std::map<...> m;

// Wrong:
m.insert(nh);
nh.value() = new_value;

// Right:
auto it = m.insert(nh);
it->second = new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The object at `nh` will be copied out of, but the returned iterator will point to the new copy that exists inside the map.

The first example is indeed wrong, since `nh` can't be used for anything other than destruction after being moved from.

That's generally true, even without the r-value form:  the map creates a value that lives inside its own data structure, and is a *copy* of the one being passed in to `insert`.  For the regular (const &) form, you understand that changing the original will not affect the `map`!

Comment: Much of the point of node handles is that no copying is involved: the node simply changes ownership between the map and the handle, and there is no non-rvalue `insert(const node_type&)` or so.  However, the handle will become empty, so the basic advice is correct.